# Wakeup from suspend with bluetooth mouse

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth, wake-up

I was using my usb mouse to wake up my Windows machine from suspend, but now I have a bluetooth mouse and the power management options doesn't appear for '*Targus Soft-Touch Bluetooth Mouse*' in device manager.

Those options extists for '*Dell Wireless 380 Bluetooth 4.0 Module*' but the '*Allow device to wake Computer*' is disabled.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Under the mouse section, the '_Mouse compatible con HID_' item has already checked the '_Allow device to wake Computer_' option.

Comment: Not possible, Bluetooth is off in suspension.

Comment: I'm not sure of that... with this command I see bluetooth devices:
`POWERCFG /DEVICEQUERY wake_from_any`

Others commands usefull:
To see the list of devices ready to Wake Up the computer:
`POWERCFG /DEVICEQUERY wake_armed`

To see the list of devices that are able to Wake Up the computer:
`POWERCFG /DEVICEQUERY wake_programmable`

To enable a devices to Wake Up the computer:
`POWERCFG /DEVICEENABLEWAKE "device_name"`